# Passing props in protected route reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using protected routes in my reactjs application and I would like to know how to pass props in a protected route or if there is a more elegant way to solve my problem.

The reason why I feel the need to pass a props in a protected route, is that the logout button lies within the protected components and I need to communicate to the parent component, which contains all the routes, that the user is trying to log out.

Here is the relevant code:

Parent component:

```
render() {
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            isAuthenticated === true
            ? <Component {...props} /*I tried inserting handleLogout={this.handleLogout} here */ />
            : <Redirect to="/Login"/>
        )} />
    )

return (
<HashRouter basename={BASE_URL}>
    <div className="stories-module">
    <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path={'/login'}
        component={Login}
      />
    <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path={'/Main/'}
        component={Main}
    />
</HashRouter>
)};
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how else I could resolve this issue.

Is it considered bad practice to pass props in a route component? If so, how else can I handle this and if not, how do I pass the prop properly?

Comment: What you are trying should work but you may move your `PrivateRoute` declaration outside of the class scope.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Declare your `PrivateRoute` outside of the class :

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, handleLogout, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            isAuthenticated === true
            ? <Component {...props} handleLogout={handleLogout} />
            : <Redirect to="/Login"/>
        )} />
);
```

Then pass `handleLogout` to your `PrivateRoute` props :

```
render() {
    return (
        <HashRouter basename={BASE_URL}>
            <div className="stories-module">
                <Route
                     exact
                     path={'/login'}
                     component={Login}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                     exact
                     path={'/Main/'}
                     component={Main}
                     handleLogout={this.handleLogout}
                     isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
                />
            </div>
        </HashRouter>
    )
};
```

You may want to declare you `PrivateRoute` like below in order to pass any prop to the component by spreading all props :

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            isAuthenticated === true
            ? <Component {...props} {...rest} />
            : <Redirect to="/Login"/>
        )} />
);
```

Comment: @A.S.J You're welcome, just one question, is your login route  intended to be private ?

Comment: No, the login should be public. Why are you asking?

Comment: Because it's declared as a PrivateRoute in the code so you should'nt have access to it on logout.

Comment: Oh yeah that's not my actual code, that was a silly mistake. In my app it's public, not sure what I was thinking

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more general solution to pass as many props to the component as you want:

```
render() {
  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, data, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated === true
        ? <Component {...props} {...data} />
        : <Redirect to="/Login"/>
    )} />
  );

  return (
    <HashRouter basename={BASE_URL}>
      <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path={'/login'}
        component={Login}
        data={{
            handleLogout=this.handleLogout,
            ...
            someProp=this.prop
        }}
      />
      <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path={'/Main/'}
        component={Main}
        data={{
            handleLogout=this.handleLogout,
            ...
            someProp=this.prop
        }}
      />
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: The above failed for me until I changed ```handleLogout=this.handleLogout``` to ```handleLogout:this.handleLogout```

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra prop to your `PrivateRoute` HOC

```
render() {
  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, handleLogout, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated === true
        ? <Component handleLogout={handleLogout} {...props} />
        : <Redirect to="/Login"/>
    )} />
  );

  return (
    <HashRouter basename={BASE_URL}>
      <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path={'/login'}
        component={Login}
        handleLogout={this.handleLogout}
      />
      <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path={'/Main/'}
        component={Main}
        handleLogout={this.handleLogout}
      />
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```